# iOS webview swipegesturerecognizer and zoom

Tags: ios, webview, zooming, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my app i have a webview with left and right swipegesturerecognizers. The problem is when i zoom in webview. It seems that swipegesturerecognizers are disturbing the webview scrollview delegate and webview zoom works bad. How can i do this correctly?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
  swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
  swipeRight.delegate = self;
  [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
  swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
  swipeLeft.delegate = self;
  [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)swipeRightAction:(id)ignored
{
  NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
  //add Function
}

- (void)swipeLeftAction:(id)ignored
{
  NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
  //add Function
}
```

I solved it changing above delegate method with this one:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! A better layout would be to enter your solution _as an answer_. Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question and even (after 48 hours) to accept your own answer. This helps future users much more. And you get more rep because people can upvote both your question and your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it changing above delegate method with this one:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already answered your own question, but I'm going to add this answer for people who find this in the future:

If you only need to support iOS 8+, you can use `WKWebView` from the new `WebKit` framework, which replaces `UIWebView`. `WKWebView` supports back/forward swipes out of the box (you'll need to set its `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` property to `YES` (the default is `NO`)). This means you won't need to add your own gesture recognisers for back/forward swipes.

It behaves just like Safari, which means it nicely handles the distinction between a forward/back swipe and a zoom gesture.